# Conditional CSS on 2 divs

Tags: html, css

Hi I have an HTML page where I want to include CSS only if two conditions are met.

The HTML page will always have the div with id flipbook-page3-front

The HTML page will sometimes have the div with id pagesFlipbook

These divs are not siblings and are not after each other

I want to create some CSS on flipbook-page3-front  only if the div pagesFlipbook is present. Is it possible. This is my CSS without any conditions:

```
.flipbook-page3-front{
  width: 4000px !important; /*LARGEST WIDTH OF SCALED IMAGES*/
  left: -800px !important;
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the structure of the html otherwise there is no way we can answer

Answer (score 0):

This will work only if you have class `pagesFlipbook` of parent div so it will affect.

Write conditional CSS like this.

`.pagesFlipbook .flipbook-page3-front { /* write css */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, please see the code below...

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#pagesFlipbook')
        if(element != null){
            document.querySelector('#flipbook-page3-front').classList.add('myconditionalclass')
        }
```

You can declare in your CSS the following class to complete this...

```
.myconditionalclass{
width: 4000px !important; /*LARGEST WIDTH OF SCALED IMAGES*/
  left: -800px !important;
}
```